# How to overwrite files with Copy-Item in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy content of a folder, but there are two files which I would like to exclude. The rest of all the content should be copied to a new location and existing content on that new location should be overwritten.

This is my script. It works fine if my destination folder is empty, but if I have files and folder, it doesn't overwrite them.

```
$copyAdmin = $unzipAdmin + "/Content/*"
$exclude = @('Web.config','Deploy')
Copy-Item  -Path $copyAdmin -Destination $AdminPath -Exclude $exclude -Recurse -force
```

Comment: Why not use [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) instead?

Comment: This should work..is there an error message? If this is part of deployment script, maybe the files become locked after copying(which is what would happen if IIS/Website was started).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy files from source directory to target directory and exclude specific file types from specified directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771291/copy-files-from-source-directory-to-target-directory-and-exclude-specific-file-t)

Comment: @raf there is no error . if i do copy paste manually than everything works fine, old files and folders gets over written manually. but with powershell script it only works with target folder is empty than it will not copy web.config file and deploy folder. but say for example if i already have content in destination folder than copy command only copies those files which are missing in destination

Comment: Is `$AdminPath` defined correctly in your script?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As I understand `Copy-Item -Exclude` then you are doing it correct. What I usually do, get 1'st, and then do after, so what about using `Get-Item` as in

```
Get-Item -Path $copyAdmin -Exclude $exclude |
Copy-Item  -Path $copyAdmin -Destination $AdminPath -Recurse -force
```

Comment: Any time, glad to help.

Comment: Why did you add "-Recurse" ?

Comment: @Ismoh
If you have any sub-folders in the folder you like to copy. If you do use it, it will not copy sub folders.

Answer (score 6):

Robocopy is designed for reliable copying with many copy options, file selection restart, etc.

`/xf` to excludes files and  `/e` for subdirectories:

```
robocopy $copyAdmin $AdminPath /e /xf "web.config" "Deploy"
```

Comment: Probably not what the OP was looking for, but it helped me :-)

Comment: Copy from one path to the other (`$copyAdmin $AdminPath`) the `/xf` switch defines which files to exclude i.e. `web.config` and `Deploy`

Answer (score 4):

How about calling the .NET Framework methods?

You can do ANYTHING with them... :

```
[System.IO.File]::Copy($src, $dest, $true);
```

The `$true` argument makes it overwrite.